# javascript: split a string into an array with different delimiters

Tags: javascript, string

I have an arithmetic string that I want to parse to get the result. The best idea I have come up with so far is to convert the string to an array, but I am not sure what the correct (and cross compatible) way to do this is.

The string I have to parse is "-3-6-9-3+10-3-5-2" (D&D damage rolls and resistance for an initiative tracker). To get a usable array, I need to split this by the operator of + or -, but not lose the operator since I need to know which operation to perform.

Is there a way to do this in JavaScript?

This is the array I hope to get back: ["-3","-6","-9","-3","+10","-3","-5","-2"]

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split#Example:_Capturing_parentheses . Alternatively: [Lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: So do you want the final array to be `["-3","-6",...,"-2"]` or `["-",3,"-",6,...,"-",2]` ?

Comment: Sorry, I should have included that in my question. I edited the question to include the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using [capturing parens](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split#Example:_Capturing_parentheses) is certainly a valid approach, I'd recommend using lookahead split:

```
var str = '-3-6-9-3+10-3-5-2';
str.split(/(?=[-+])/); // no need to check for digits here actually
// ["-3", "-6", "-9", "-3", "+10", "-3", "-5", "-2"]
```

In this case, each split point will be placed *before* the sign (i.e., `+` or `-`).

Answer (score 1):

You can split an rejoin, adding a different delimiter to use for a final split by both:

```
var x = '-3-6-9-3+10-3-5-2';
var y = x.split('-').join(';-;').split('+').join(';+;').split(';');
//["", "-", "3", "-", "6", "-", "9", "-", "3", ...]
```

`y` is an array which splits the original string on the `-` and `+` characters, but then adds them back into the array in their original places.

If you want to keep the `+` and `-` characters with their characters, remove the second `;` from the joins.

```
var y = x.split('-').join(';-').split('+').join(';+').split(';');
//["", "-3", "-6", "-9", "-3", "+10", "-3", "-5", "-2"]
```

Comment: You can use `reduce` on the final array to write a summing function.